# How to select id from dropdown with default value and color,options and incentives

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to select a specific value from dropdown.As I did for previous drop down selection same way I did for this but it does not work.

The link of the page is :

https://secure.bestprice.rankingsandreviews.com/nc/configurator/307715

I want to select "Convertible LT 1LT" as the style,"Hyper Metallic Blue" as color and any options and incentives to be selected

Here is the my code :

```
def test_price

  browser.div(:id => 's2id_select_style').click

  browser.select_list(:id => 'select_style').send_keys('Coupe LS')

  browser.li(:class => 'exterior-color-swatch color-swatch').p(:text => 'Hyper Blue Metallic').select

  browser.li(:class => 'price update-opts').options(:text => '$395').select

  browser.li(:class => 'price update-incs').options(:text => '$1000').select
```

Comment: send_keys function can't be called for select_list, select can't be called for p, it can not be called for option object(not for options either)

Comment: I have written an answer below, can you check that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
browser.goto('https://secure.bestprice.rankingsandreviews.com/nc/configurator/307715')

browser.div(:id => 's2id_select_style').click

browser.element(xpath: ".//*[@id='select2-drop']/div/input").send_keys('Convertible LT 1LT',:tab)

browser.element(id: 'edit_color').click

browser.img(title: 'Hyper Blue Metallic').click

browser.span(text: 'Save & Update').click
```

I don't know how to choose 14 and 1000 (last two lines of code of yours) manually as well so I left it. If you tell me how do I choose manually, I include the code for that as well. But let me know whether above code works for you!

Comment: Welcome! @SumeetKore

Comment: do you know how to check if a text is present in url @RAJ

Comment: @SumeetKore yes, `if browser.url.include? 'something' `